# How to implement Uber V2 UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement the same style of UI as the new Uber iOS app, at least the pull-up view. I am wondering if this is a UICollectionView or a UITableView. How are the inner horizontal scrollable views implemented? I have done something like this before in iOS back in 2009, but that was UITableView inside a UITableView. Just wondering if UICollectionView is what should be used now?

Also, how do they allow you to drag the view up and then switch to a new view?

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be simply animating transitions. There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43530231/5155181) on SO addressing this for the card implementations used in Apple’s Music and Mail apps. As for the horizontal swiping, I would use a collection view nowadays but I don’t see it wrong using a tableView.
Hope this will help