# iOS Swift: How to achieve stack of cards like user interface?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to achieve below design where four different view controllers will be stacked back to back. Reference image below -

[image]

Each view controller will have table views with different data dynamically. The view controllers can be switched by swiping from right.

I know that UIPageViewController is suitable for this kind of pagination approach. **But, I am afraid whether this kind of stacked page view is achievable?**

I haven't started anything and I need some idea to start with. First of all, is it possible to do this?

Please let me know if it's not clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530231/is-there-a-public-api-for-card-view-ui-that-can-be-seen-across-ios-10?

Comment: I’d suggest creating a container view controller and add child view controllers to it.

Comment: Okay @AuRis. But, how can I show pages on top of each other using container view?

Comment: Core animation and affine transforms should be able to do this.

Comment: Okay useful info. But it would be helpful if you can post some code snippets?

Comment: @Ahmad- not exactly what you have referred!!

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick I have added an answer with example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment you could create a container view controller where you'd add your child view controllers. How you present and remove them it's up to you. I added a swipe gesture to remove them from `childViewControllers` array one by one, but you could elaborate with animations, etc. Here is the example:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeGesturRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipe))
        swipeGesturRecognizer.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesturRecognizer)

        var index = 0
        let amount = 5
        while index < amount {
            let childViewController = UIViewController()
            childViewController.view
            .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            let hue = 1.0 / CGFloat(index)
            childViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.5, alpha: 1)
            childViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(amount - index) * 10, dy: 80.0).offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -CGFloat(amount - index) * 10.0)
            childViewController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            childViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
            self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
            childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            index += 1
        }
    }

    // Removes child view controlelrs one by one when swiped left
    @objc func didSwipe() {
        guard let childViewController = childViewControllers.last else {
            return
        }
        childViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        childViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks much

Comment: If I want to modify this to create a infinite loop (instead of deleting the child view on swipe, push it to last index), what should I do? Any hints?