# What is the name of this dismissable viewcontrollable in iOS?

Tags: ios

[image: viewcontroller]

I just want to know is this a custom view controller or it is something provided by apple, if thats the case what is its name?

Comment: Seem like this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530231/is-there-a-public-api-for-card-view-ui-that-can-be-seen-across-ios-10

Comment: https://github.com/epeschard/CardsUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a custom modal view controller which you can animate in with [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator](http://UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator).  If you don't want to mess with the code then consider using the [Hero](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) pod which can acheive a similar effect.

Comment: thank you josh i thought it was a predefined view controller as i saw it in so many apps.