# Name of iOS ui element

Tags: ios, uielement

How does this half screen scrollable pop up elememt is called in iOS? Have seen it in many apps so I guess it should be native one.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's common, it is not a standard UIKit element. It's a custom presented view controller (not a standard configuration). You'll need a custom transition animation and presentation controller along with gesture recognizers for dismissal. (There are lots of tutorials showing you how to do that.)

New in iOS 13, all presented view controllers have this general configuration by default (called "sheet" or "card"), but not half-screen like the one you've shown (they almost fill the screen).

Comment: Oh really? Just I’ve seen many times this thing with a gray line as sort of drag action indicator ot the top . It looks so similar in many apps so I tought it should be standard.

Comment: I think the history is that Apple started doing this in the Music app and similar, without leaking it out as a standard element, and everyone started saying "How do they do that?" and rolling their own. That's why Apple finally provided something similar in iOS 13.

Comment: For some techniques, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530231/is-there-a-public-api-for-card-view-ui-that-can-be-seen-across-ios-10 - I suppose I really should have marked this question as a duplicate rather than answering...

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks